# perforce workspace command line

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to understand how perorce work and I'm struggling with command line
I have a single depot with 3 project inside
so depot:

- projectA
- projectB

now I have 2 workspaces, one mapped only on projectA and one on projectB.

Here I have my trouble , using interface everything works
but with command line I have not enough knoledge on perforce.
I use 
p4 -c workspacA //to switch workspace

then I run: p4 cstat

and it give me all the information about changelist contained in all depot
not only depot/projectA

But I woul like to enter in a workspace and run my command only on that workspace

Is this normal? I see that I need to specify my depot mapping but this seems strange to me.
Can someone clarify me this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Do:

```
p4 set P4CLIENT=workspaceA
```

If you use `-c workspaceA` it applies only to that one command, whereas `p4 set` is persistent.

I also recommend looking at documentation on `P4CONFIG`, which lets you associate Perforce config settings with local directories (so you switch workspaces automatically when you `cd` to a different workspace root).

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v16.2/cmdref/P4CONFIG.html

Comment: I still have the same problem using "p4 set P4CLIENT=workspaceA" then I run a simple p4 cstat and I get all changelist in depot instead of only workspaceA changleslist

Comment: My guess is that your workspaces aren't really set up the way you've described.  I'd recommend going over to forums.perforce.com and posting this question along with the client spec(s) in question so people can help you debug.